# Consortium Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

We have deployed consortium ethereum block chain in azure portal. I don't have access to the azure portal except the cloud url. By using the cloud url i have wrote the nodejs code with web3 api to get the balance and unlock the account and send the transaction.I got the getBalance but When i am trying to unlock the account it's showing me error "Failed to unlock the personal_unlock account is not available or does'nt exist" and i am unable to proceed further for the transaction. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the Ethereum node started does not expose `personal` api of the geth interface. This can be changed by starting the rpc server with the rpcapi flag specifying which api's of geth to expose on RPC. By default when a rpc server is started it does not expose all the api of geth through RPC due to security reasons. You can find how to start a node by exposing required modules of the geth API [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#how-to).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Do u mean that we should run those commands in azure?

Comment: Yes, you will have to restart the RPC server exposing the required API.